# deep hierarchy data tree

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree, hierarchy

I have an array of objects in which i have few properties like `fullName` and `reportingTo`  , then i have another object which is of ceo, the final data structure is to be every object has a `fullName` now if in any other object if the `reportingTo` matches with their name that object must be removed from array and added in children property, i have been able to do it only for a few levels but i need it dynamic so even if there is 100 parents it must work, i am putting the data below and what ever i have been able to do so far

```
let data = [
  {
    department: "development",
    designation: "lead",
    employeeId: "2",
    fullName: "Kashif",
    reportingTo: "Rashid",
    workEmail: "lead@gmail.com",
    workPhone: "2222222222",
  },

  {
    department: "development",
    designation: "UI Developer",
    employeeId: "3",
    fullName: "Sharif",
    reportingTo: "Rashid",
    workEmail: "ui@gmail.com",
    workPhone: "3333333333",
  },
  {
    department: "development",
    designation: "UX Developer",
    employeeId: "4",
    fullName: "Naveen",
    reportingTo: "Rashid",
    workEmail: "ux@gmail.com",
    workPhone: "4444444444",
  },
  {
    department: "development",
    designation: "Developer",
    employeeId: "5",
    fullName: "Mani",
    reportingTo: "Kiran",
    workEmail: "developer@gmail.com",
    workPhone: "5555555555",
  },

  {
    department: "development",
    designation: "Developer",
    employeeId: "6",
    fullName: "Joseph",
    reportingTo: "kiran",
    workEmail: "developer@gmail.com",
    workPhone: "6666666666",
  },
  {
    department: "development",
    designation: "Developer",
    employeeId: "7",
    fullName: "Waseem",
    reportingTo: "Mani",
    workEmail: "developer@gmail.com",
    workPhone: "6666666666",
  },
  {
    department: "development",
    designation: "Developer",
    employeeId: "8",
    fullName: "Munir",
    reportingTo: "Waseem",
    workEmail: "developer@gmail.com",
    workPhone: "6666666666",
  },
  {
    department: "development",
    designation: "Developer",
    employeeId: "9",
    fullName: "Maaz",
    reportingTo: "Munir",
    workEmail: "developer@gmail.com",
    workPhone: "6666666666",
  },
  {
    department: "development",
    designation: "Developer",
    employeeId: "10",
    fullName: "Hazma",
    reportingTo: "Maaz",
    workEmail: "developer@gmail.com",
    workPhone: "6666666666",
  },
  {
    department: "development",
    designation: "Developer",
    employeeId: "11",
    fullName: "Muhammad",
    reportingTo: "Maaz",
    workEmail: "developer@gmail.com",
    workPhone: "6666666666",
  },
  {
    department: "development",
    designation: "Developer",
    employeeId: "11",
    fullName: "Kiran",
    reportingTo: "Rashid",
    workEmail: "developer@gmail.com",
    workPhone: "6666666666",
  },
];

let ceo = {
  department: "management",
  designation: "ceo",
  employeeId: "1",
  fullName: "Rashid",
  reportingTo: "null",
  workEmail: "ceo@gmail.com",
  workPhone: "1111111111",
};


const renderChildren = (list, reportingTo) => {
  let array = [];
  let dataArray = [...list];

  dataArray.map((item, i) => {
    if (item.reportingTo == reportingTo) {
      array.push(item);
      list.splice(i, 1);
    }
  });
  return array;
};

let ceoChildren = renderChildren(data, "Rashid"); // In this case we are getting all the employees who are reporting to ceo whose name is Rashid
```

Expected Result should be

```
let data = {
  department: "management",
  designation: "ceo",
  employeeId: "1",
  fullName: "Rashid",
  reportingTo: "null",
  workEmail: "ceo@gmail.com",
  workPhone: "1111111111",
  children: [
    {
      department: "development",
      designation: "lead",
      employeeId: "2",
      fullName: "Kashif",
      reportingTo: "Rashid",
      workEmail: "lead@gmail.com",
      workPhone: "2222222222",
    },
    {
      department: "development",
      designation: "Developer",
      employeeId: "11",
      fullName: "Kiran",
      reportingTo: "Rashid",
      workEmail: "developer@gmail.com",
      workPhone: "6666666666",
      children: [
        {
          department: "development",
          designation: "Developer",
          employeeId: "5",
          fullName: "Mani",
          reportingTo: "Kiran",
          workEmail: "developer@gmail.com",
          workPhone: "5555555555",
          children: [
            {
              department: "development",
              designation: "Developer",
              employeeId: "7",
              fullName: "Waseem",
              reportingTo: "Mani",
              workEmail: "developer@gmail.com",
              workPhone: "6666666666",
              children: [
                {
                  department: "development",
                  designation: "Developer",
                  employeeId: "8",
                  fullName: "Munir",
                  reportingTo: "Waseem",
                  workEmail: "developer@gmail.com",
                  workPhone: "6666666666",
                  children: [
                    {
                      department: "development",
                      designation: "Developer",
                      employeeId: "9",
                      fullName: "Maaz",
                      reportingTo: "Munir",
                      workEmail: "developer@gmail.com",
                      workPhone: "6666666666",
                      children: [
                        {
                          department: "development",
                          designation: "Developer",
                          employeeId: "10",
                          fullName: "Hazma",
                          reportingTo: "Maaz",
                          workEmail: "developer@gmail.com",
                          workPhone: "6666666666",
                        },
                        {
                          department: "development",
                          designation: "Developer",
                          employeeId: "11",
                          fullName: "Muhammad",
                          reportingTo: "Maaz",
                          workEmail: "developer@gmail.com",
                          workPhone: "6666666666",
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },

        {
          department: "development",
          designation: "Developer",
          employeeId: "6",
          fullName: "Joseph",
          reportingTo: "Kiran",
          workEmail: "developer@gmail.com",
          workPhone: "6666666666",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      department: "development",
      designation: "UI Developer",
      employeeId: "3",
      fullName: "Sharif",
      reportingTo: "Rashid",
      workEmail: "ui@gmail.com",
      workPhone: "3333333333",
    },
    {
      department: "development",
      designation: "UX Developer",
      employeeId: "4",
      fullName: "Naveen",
      reportingTo: "Rashid",
      workEmail: "ux@gmail.com",
      workPhone: "4444444444",
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: Please add your code to your question.

Comment: There is a function in the question if you scroll down, i have tried many things but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You could create a plain object (as dictionary), keyed by the names, and where each key has as corresponding value the object that relates to that name.

Then use the `fullName`, `reportingTo` pairs to populate `children` arrays with the objects found for those names.

Finally, return an object that has both the list of root(s) and the dictionary for looking up nodes by name.

Here is an implementation:

```js
function createTree(data) {
    const nodes = Object.fromEntries(data.map(o => [o.fullName, o]));
    const roots = [];
    nodes.null = { children: roots };
    for (let {fullName, reportingTo} of data) {
        (nodes[reportingTo].children ??= []).push(nodes[fullName]);
    }
    return {nodes,roots};
}

const data = [{department: "development",designation: "lead",employeeId: "2",fullName: "Kashif",reportingTo: "Rashid",workEmail: "lead@gmail.com",workPhone: "2222222222",},{department: "development",designation: "UI Developer",employeeId: "3",fullName: "Sharif",reportingTo: "Rashid",workEmail: "ui@gmail.com",workPhone: "3333333333",},{department: "development",designation: "UX Developer",employeeId: "4",fullName: "Naveen",reportingTo: "Rashid",workEmail: "ux@gmail.com",workPhone: "4444444444",},{department: "development",designation: "Developer",employeeId: "5",fullName: "Mani",reportingTo: "Kiran",workEmail: "developer@gmail.com",workPhone: "5555555555",},{department: "development",designation: "Developer",employeeId: "6",fullName: "Joseph",reportingTo: "Kiran",workEmail: "developer@gmail.com",workPhone: "6666666666",},{department: "development",designation: "Developer",employeeId: "7",fullName: "Waseem",reportingTo: "Mani",workEmail: "developer@gmail.com",workPhone: "6666666666",},{department: "development",designation: "Developer",employeeId: "8",fullName: "Munir",reportingTo: "Waseem",workEmail: "developer@gmail.com",workPhone: "6666666666",},{department: "development",designation: "Developer",employeeId: "9",fullName: "Maaz",reportingTo: "Munir",workEmail: "developer@gmail.com",workPhone: "6666666666",},{department: "development",designation: "Developer",employeeId: "10",fullName: "Hazma",reportingTo: "Maaz",workEmail: "developer@gmail.com",workPhone: "6666666666",},{department: "development",designation: "Developer",employeeId: "11",fullName: "Muhammad",reportingTo: "Maaz",workEmail: "developer@gmail.com",workPhone: "6666666666",},{department: "development",designation: "Developer",employeeId: "11",fullName: "Kiran",reportingTo: "Rashid",workEmail: "developer@gmail.com",workPhone: "6666666666",},];
const ceo = {department: "management",designation: "ceo",employeeId: "1",fullName: "Rashid",reportingTo: "null",workEmail: "ceo@gmail.com",workPhone: "1111111111",};

// Initialise tree -- no need to distinguish the ceo; could be in same array
const tree = createTree(data.concat(ceo));
// Perform access in tree by name:
const ceoChildren = tree.nodes["Rashid"];
console.log(ceoChildren);
// Or by root:
const root = tree.roots[0];
console.log(root === ceoChildren); // true
```